# compiling protobuf while getting proper imports

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers

My project is supposed to be pip installable. I'm using setuptools. I have a project structure that is like this:

```
.
|-- myPackage
|   |-- proto
|   |    `-- b.proto
|   `A .py
```

In my setup.py I am using protoc.main() to generate my protobuf python files. So the structure ends up looking like this:

```
.
|-- myPackage
|   |-- proto
|   |    `-- b.proto
|   `A .py
|   `Gen1 .py
|   `Gen2 .py
```

The issue arrises when I pip install my package and try to use the functions in my A.py (which imports gen1.py and gen2.py). It throws the error, no gen1 module found. Why is this the case? I see the gen1 and gen2 files in my venv package. The package is ran through a ADO pipeline and the setup.py compiles the protobuf files, it looks something like this:

```
myCompileClas:
|  def compile_my_proto()

compile_my_proto()

setup()
```

It seems like manually changing the import statement in gen1 to import gen2 like this:
`from . import gen2 as x`
seems to work. But I know I cant change the way the import statement is without manually change it or running an external script.

Comment: IIUC, I'd encourage you to **not** `protoc` (compile) your Protobufs on package installation. I don't know why it isn't working for you but I suspect there's some race condition arising. Protobuf sources need only be compiled if language stubs are needed and not available. I assume your Protobuf sources aren't changing but that your code needs to use them. For this reason, bundle the generated (!) Python stubs and upgrade the entire package (with new stubs) whenever you change the Protobuf srouces.